# Javascript - How to zoom background-image

Tags: javascript, image, background, resize, zooming

I have div with fixed size and background-image in there. The image is much larger, than the container, but i have set background-position to show only chosen part of image. This works it's supposed to work.
I need to make "zoom in" and "zoom out" buttons for  backgroundImage(in original ratio), but without changing size of it's container.

Thank you for any advice.
P.S.: I need pure javascript/css way.

Comment: I've answered **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300673/how-do-i-zoom-a-background-image-on-a-div-with-background-size/21300704#21300704)**, now you can achieve this using CSS only

Answer (score -1):

How about some zoom plugins (Smooth Zoom Pan, jqZoom and others)?  This [aricle](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/10/jquery-image-zoom.html) for example