# how do I zoom a background image on a div with background-size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image

I want a div element to stretch across that is 33% width with a background image done in css

```
background-image:url(); background-size:cover
```

How do I animate a zoom-in of the image of the background in the div on mouseover or mouseneter, is there a plugin that can do this? The background div has to use background-size:cover because it's an elastic page.

I don't have a fiddle yet cos I don't know where or how to start

Answer (score 60, accepted):

#### Answer for those who wants to hack CSS transitioning zooming to get applied on background-size: cover; 

-- if not, than read the second section for standard ways to achieve such effect

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div></div>
    <p>hello</p>
</div>


html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div.wrap {
    height: 33%;
    width: 33%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

div.wrap > div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    transform: scale(1,1);
    background-image: url('http://pimg.tradeindia.com/00288122/b/0/Our-Valuable-Client-List-Click-on-Image-.jpg');
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}

div.wrap:hover > div {
    -moz-transform: scale(2,2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2,2);
    transform: scale(2,2);    
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s3hWj/4/) *(Using `background-size: cover;` to transition/zoom the element)*

As you said that transitioning the `cover` size is necessary, so I came up with the trick which I had told you previously, here I have a child element nested under `position: relative;` element where am having the child element set to `position: absolute;` with `background-image` having `background-size` set to `cover` and then on `hover` of parent, I zoom in the element using the `transform: scale(2,2);` property.

Also, a crucial thing while working with this solution is that we need to set the `z-index` of the `position: absolute;` element lower than what the elements you will be placing inside, so it will act like a `background`

---

#### Answer for those who want to go clean with HTML and CSS

You cannot animate a `background-size` if it's value is `cover` so either you will need `px` or `%`, or you can also use an `img` tag with `transform: scale(2,2);` property.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s3hWj/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/s3hWj/567/) *(zoom-in or zoom-out from the center)*

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: url('http://pimg.tradeindia.com/00288122/b/0/Our-Valuable-Client-List-Click-on-Image-.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}

div:hover {
    background-size: 150% 150%;
}
```

---

If you want to stick with `background-size: cover;` than you will have to wrap entire element inside a wrapper element having fixed dimensions with `overflow: hidden;` and than scale the child element on `hover` of parent element.

---

As you commented, for an `img` tag example, you can use `transform: scale(2,2);` to achieve that with the parent element set to `overflow: hidden;`

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/s3hWj/3/)

```
div {
    height:300px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div img {
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    transform: scale(1,1);
}

div:hover img {
    -moz-transform: scale(2,2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2,2);
    transform: scale(2,2);
}
```

Comment: How do then have the img tag overflow it parent div element so I can accomplish the zoom in look cos the img wont stretch to it's full width in the it's parent div. Can you make me a jsFiddle example on how to do this

Comment: Thanks for example. The problem I have now is that the background-image stretches because the div element is set at 33% and not a fixed width so what can you do change it so it stays in proportion.

Comment: Thanks heaps for you're answers I will give you're official answer a go and see if I cn get it to work. I The only problem I'm having is the animation on IE11 when it scales the transform it just jerks into the transform know of any tricks to fix that

Comment: @KDM Try `zoom` but chrome will make it 2x larger :)

Comment: Good set of answers, I came here to confirm I couldn't animate with cover, was hoping to not add an extra div, oh well.

Comment: Transition on all properties? Very bad practise.

Comment: @M_Willett What's bad in that?

Answer (score -3):

```
<script>
    function animate(){
        document.getElementById('a').style.webkitTransitionDuration='1s';
        document.getElementById('a').style.backgroundSize="200% 200%";
    }
</script>
<div id="a" onmouseover="animate()" style="width: 200px; height: 70px; border: 1px solid; background: url('http://www.wpclipart.com/food/fruit/apple/apples_4/apple_honeycrisp_small.png') no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%; ">
</div>
```

You can do something like this for webkit browsers.

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/HW2uj/)

Comment: Do you really use this method in your own projects? background-size set to `cover` means clearly that ones needs to respect time image's aspect ratio. Suggesting something like *Just use 200%* is quite odd at least.