# Div not expanding in width when zooming in

Tags: html, css

I have a div that's centered, the width set to 50%, and the max-width set to 100%. However, when I zooms in, the width does not increase at all while the height increases every time I zooms in. Why is that happening even though I set the max-width to 100%, and how do I fix it? Thanks.

```
#outer {
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #F5F5F5;
border: 1px dotted black;
width: 50%;
max-width: 100%;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 1%;
}

<div id = 'outer"></div>
```

P.S: I still want to use percentage over pixels.

Comment: What's the expected behaviour? If you set `width: 50%`, it's gonna be like that with or without zoom.

Comment: Are you looking to do something like this?
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300673/how-do-i-zoom-a-background-image-on-a-div-with-background-size/21300704#21300704>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understood what you want.
Your problem is where you put your `<div>`.

As you probably know, percentage is a relative measure. In particular, `width: 50%` is relative to parent's width.

#### Case 1

Parent's width is `100%`. In this case, your `div`'s width will allways be `50%` of `100%` which is `50%` *of the screen* even if you zoom in/out.

#### Case 2

Parent div has an absolute width (for example `500px`). Then, your `div`'s width will be `50%` of `500px`, which is `250px`. When you zoom in/out, this will change.

Here is a jsfiddle showing both cases. Hope this helps: https://jsfiddle.net/jormaechea/om91sody/