# expand div on hover, with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I have a littre problem.

Curently, I have a struture like this (run in full page)

```css
.color{
    background : red;
}

.color-green{
    background : green;
}

.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid color-green vertical-align">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
        <h1>Titre</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet animi aspernatur assumenda atque, commodi corporis deserunt eius enim laborum natus obcaecati optio, quidem quos repudiandae saepe tempora tempore unde veritatis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
        <h1>Titre</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet animi aspernatur assumenda atque, commodi corporis deserunt eius enim laborum natus obcaecati optio, quidem quos repudiandae saepe tempora tempore unde veritatis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
        <h1>Titre</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet animi aspernatur assumenda atque, commodi corporis deserunt eius enim laborum natus obcaecati optio, quidem quos repudiandae saepe tempora tempore unde veritatis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I would like to expand div on hover independently like this 
[image]

But i use bootstrap, and I don't know how to make that with bootstrap..

if you have an idea or track to follow

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on `:hover`, you can use `transform: scale()` to make the element bigger, change the `background`, and add `position: relative; z-index: 1;` to keep that element on top of it's siblings. And use `transition` to create a smooth transition, if you want that.

```css
.color{
    background : red;
}

.color-green{
    background : green;
}

.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.color-green > .row > .text-center {
  transition: transform .25s, background .25s;
}
.color-green > .row > .text-center:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  background: #8dc63f;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid color-green vertical-align">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
        <h1>Titre</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet animi aspernatur assumenda atque, commodi corporis deserunt eius enim laborum natus obcaecati optio, quidem quos repudiandae saepe tempora tempore unde veritatis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
        <h1>Titre</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet animi aspernatur assumenda atque, commodi corporis deserunt eius enim laborum natus obcaecati optio, quidem quos repudiandae saepe tempora tempore unde veritatis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
        <h1>Titre</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet animi aspernatur assumenda atque, commodi corporis deserunt eius enim laborum natus obcaecati optio, quidem quos repudiandae saepe tempora tempore unde veritatis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If I would like to expand only the background not the text, how i do that ?

Comment: @simonmnt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300673/how-do-i-zoom-a-background-image-on-a-div-with-background-size

Comment: Thanks, but is not the effect i search. Do you have an idea how to get the same effect without the scale zoom, isolated the text and just background moove

Comment: @simonmnt that zooms the background and not the text. You change `background-size` on `:hover`

Comment: Ok, I just change `scale` by the `background-size`  on `:hover` ?

Comment: @simonmnt yes, if you read the post I linked to, the accepted solution has a few approaches. Use the 2nd one.

Comment: The problem with the linked post, zoom effect is inside a div. Isn't detached like a effect I try to do